# Magento module installer stuck at Update Application is not running

Tags: magento-2.1.7

When updating or adding an extension to the Magento 2.1.7 installation I get the following output in the module set up.

```
Process extensions Status:
Update application is not running

Error in Update!
Please refer to documentation Doc link to perform manual rollback.

To attempt automatic rollback, please click the "Rollback" button. 


[2017-11-29 12:27:14 UTC] An error occurred while executing job "setup:static:regenerate []": Could not complete setup:static:regenerate [] successfully: The file "/var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_NZ/css/styles-old.less" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_NZ/css/styles-old.less): Permission denied
```

the complete console output is:

```
[2017-11-29 12:25:04 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:enable []" has started
Enabled maintenance mode



 [2017-11-29 12:25:04 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:enable []" has been successfully completed
    [2017-11-29 12:25:04 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has started
    There is nothing to change in cache status

[2017-11-29 12:25:04 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has been successfully completed
[2017-11-29 07:26:02 EST] Job "update {"components":[{"name":"mollie/magento2","version":"1.1.1"}]}" has been started
[2017-11-29 07:26:02 EST] Starting composer update...
[2017-11-29 07:26:03 EST] ./composer.json has been updated

[2017-11-29 07:26:32 EST] Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Removing paragonie/constant_time_encoding (v1.0.1)
Removing Paragonie/Constant_time_encoding
- Removing composer/ca-bundle (1.0.9)
- Installing composer/ca-bundle (1.1.0)
Downloading: Connecting... Downloading: 0% Downloading: 5% Downloading: 10% Downloading: 15% Downloading: 20% Downloading: 25% Downloading: 30% Downloading: 35% Downloading: 40% Downloading: 45% Downloading: 50% Downloading: 55% Downloading: 60% Downloading: 65% Downloading: 70% Downloading: 75% Downloading: 80% Downloading: 85% Downloading: 90% Downloading: 95% Downloading: 100% Downloading: 100%

- Removing phpseclib/phpseclib (2.0.8)
- Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (2.0.9)
Downloading: Connecting... Downloading: 0%  Downloading: 5% Downloading: 10% Downloading: 15% Downloading: 20% Downloading: 25% Downloading: 30% Downloading: 35% Downloading: 40% Downloading: 45% Downloading: 50% Downloading: 55% Downloading: 60% Downloading: 65% Downloading: 70% Downloading: 75% Downloading: 80% Downloading: 85% Downloading: 90% Downloading: 95% Downloading: 100% Downloading: 100%

- Installing mollie/mollie-api-php (v1.9.4)
Downloading: Connecting... Downloading: 0%  Downloading: 5% Downloading: 10% Downloading: 15% Downloading: 20% Downloading: 25% Downloading: 30% Downloading: 35% Downloading: 40% Downloading: 45% Downloading: 50% Downloading: 55% Downloading: 60% Downloading: 65% Downloading: 70% Downloading: 75% Downloading: 80% Downloading: 85% Downloading: 90% Downloading: 95% Downloading: 100% Downloading: 100%

- Installing mollie/magento2 (1.1.1)
Downloading: Connecting... Downloading: 0%  Downloading: 35% Downloading: 75% Downloading: 100%

mollie/mollie-api-php suggests installing mollie/oauth2-mollie-php (Use OAuth to authenticate with the Mollie API. This is needed for some endpoints. Visit https://mollie.com/en/docs for more information.)
Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

[2017-11-29 07:26:32 EST] Composer update completed successfully
[2017-11-29 07:26:32 EST] Job "update {"components":[{"name":"mollie/magento2","version":"1.1.1"}]}" has successfully completed
[2017-11-29 12:27:06 UTC] Job "setup:upgrade []" has started
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Composer
/var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento
/var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Symfony
The directory '/var/www/html/magento/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/_cache
/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/adminhtml
The file "/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_NZ/css/styles-old.css" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_NZ/css/styles-old.css): Permission denied
/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/deployed_version.txt
/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/frontend
The file "/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_NZ/css/email-inline.css" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_NZ/css/email-inline.css): Permission denied
/var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub
The file "/var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_NZ/css/styles-old.less" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_NZ/css/styles-old.less): Permission denied

Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Module 'Magento_Contact':
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
Module 'Magento_Developer':
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Sales':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Ui':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Module 'Magento_Security':
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_Vault':
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_Robots':
Module 'Magento_Rss':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Module 'Magento_Integration':
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
Module 'Magento_Shipping':
Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Module 'Magento_Swagger':
Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Tax':
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
Module 'Magento_Translation':
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
Module 'Magento_Ups':
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
Module 'Magento_Usps':
Module 'Magento_Variable':
Module 'Magento_Braintree':
Module 'Magento_Version':
Module 'Magento_Webapi':
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Module 'Mageplaza_Core':
Module 'Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Mollie_Payment':
Module 'Shopial_Facebook':
Module 'Smartwave_Core':
Module 'Smartwave_Filterproducts':
Module 'Smartwave_Megamenu':
Module 'Smartwave_Porto':
Module 'Smartwave_Socialfeeds':
Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Contact':
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
Module 'Magento_Developer':
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Sales':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Ui':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Module 'Magento_Security':
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_Vault':
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_Robots':
Module 'Magento_Rss':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Module 'Magento_Integration':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
Module 'Magento_Shipping':
Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Module 'Magento_Swagger':
Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Tax':
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
Module 'Magento_Translation':
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
Module 'Magento_Ups':
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
Module 'Magento_Usps':
Module 'Magento_Variable':
Module 'Magento_Braintree':
Module 'Magento_Version':
Module 'Magento_Webapi':
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Mageplaza_Core':
Module 'Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Mollie_Payment':
Module 'Shopial_Facebook':
Module 'Smartwave_Core':
Module 'Smartwave_Filterproducts':
Module 'Smartwave_Megamenu':
Module 'Smartwave_Porto':
Module 'Smartwave_Socialfeeds':
Data install/update:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Module 'Magento_Contact':
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
Module 'Magento_Developer':
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Sales':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Ui':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Module 'Magento_Security':
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_Vault':
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_Robots':
Module 'Magento_Rss':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Module 'Magento_Integration':
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
Module 'Magento_Shipping':
Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Module 'Magento_Swagger':
Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Tax':
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
Module 'Magento_Translation':
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
Module 'Magento_Ups':
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
Module 'Magento_Usps':
Module 'Magento_Variable':
Module 'Magento_Braintree':
Module 'Magento_Version':
Module 'Magento_Webapi':
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Module 'Mageplaza_Core':
Module 'Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Mollie_Payment':
Installing data...
Module 'Shopial_Facebook':
Module 'Smartwave_Core':
Module 'Smartwave_Filterproducts':
Module 'Smartwave_Megamenu':
Module 'Smartwave_Porto':
Module 'Smartwave_Socialfeeds':
Data post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Running data recurring...
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running data recurring...
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Running data recurring...
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Module 'Magento_Contact':
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
Module 'Magento_Developer':
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Sales':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Ui':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Module 'Magento_Security':
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_Vault':
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_Robots':
Module 'Magento_Rss':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Module 'Magento_Integration':
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
Module 'Magento_Shipping':
Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Module 'Magento_Swagger':
Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Tax':
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
Module 'Magento_Translation':
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
Module 'Magento_Ups':
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
Module 'Magento_Usps':
Module 'Magento_Variable':
Module 'Magento_Braintree':
Module 'Magento_Version':
Module 'Magento_Webapi':
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Module 'Mageplaza_Core':
Module 'Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Mollie_Payment':
Module 'Shopial_Facebook':
Module 'Smartwave_Core':
Module 'Smartwave_Filterproducts':
Module 'Smartwave_Megamenu':
Module 'Smartwave_Porto':
Module 'Smartwave_Socialfeeds':
Nothing to import.
Please re-run Magento compile command. Use the command "setup:di:compile"

[2017-11-29 12:27:14 UTC] Job "setup:upgrade {"command":"setup:upgrade"}" has been successfully completed
[2017-11-29 12:27:14 UTC] Job "setup:static:regenerate []" has started

[2017-11-29 12:27:14 UTC] An error occurred while executing job "setup:static:regenerate []": Could not complete setup:static:regenerate [] successfully: The file "/var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_NZ/css/styles-old.less" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_NZ/css/styles-old.less): Permission denied
[2017-11-29 12:27:14 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:disable []" has started
Disabled maintenance mode

[2017-11-29 12:27:14 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:disable []" has been successfully completed
[2017-11-29 07:28:02 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:29:02 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:30:01 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:31:02 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:32:02 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:33:01 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:34:02 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:35:01 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:36:02 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:37:02 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
[2017-11-29 07:38:02 EST] There was an error in previous Update attempt.
```

What could I do wrong?

Comment: Any solution for this issue?